# How to show mysql records only if patient_id is different

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a sql query on this table:

[image: table1]

As you can see in this table, we have 4 records of encounter_id 20. But all 4 points to same patient_id 35. My requirement is to show encounter_id count and patient_id only if one encounter_id points to different patient_id (like encounter_id 19, which points to patient_id 38 and 29). I have used following query:

```
SELECT encounter_id, count(encounter_id) as ecount, GROUP_CONCAT(patient_id), GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM table1 group by encounter_id having ecount > 1
```

But it shows following records:

[image: results]

But it should show only encounter_id 19, since it points to different patients.

Comment: Aside from requesting priority attention, there is no need to add "please help" to every question you ask here. On a site like this it is very clear you need help, so saying so explicitly may be read as a form of begging, and as a result you may not get the assistance that you seek. Try to keep posts succinct and to the point if you can.

Comment: Please accept my apology for these mistakes. It will never happen again in future.

Comment: Thanks Vishal, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your query is that you're grabbing the number of any encounter, rather than `distinct` encounters. You just have to add the `distinct` operator to your count, and you should be fine.

`SELECT encounter_id, count(encounter_id) as ecount, GROUP_CONCAT(patient_id), GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM table1 group by encounter_id having count(distinct patient_id) > 1`

Comment: count(distinct encounter_id) will always be 1 - you're grouping by that column. should count distinct patient_id's instead.

Comment: @poncha Thank you! That's what I get for not paying full attention to the query I was editing. I've corrected the column name.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the definition of `ecount` to only count distinct patients:

```
SELECT encounter_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT patient_id) AS ecount,
  GROUP_CONCAT(patient_id) AS patient_ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids
FROM table1
GROUP BY encounter_id
HAVING ecount > 1
```

You can also add `DISTINCT` to GROUP_CONCAT if you like - that would return list of unique ids it matches. For example

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT patient_id) AS patient_ids
```